# Memory usage issue with Python csv.DictReader

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm using [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) in Python 3 to process a very large CSV file. And I found a strange memory usage issue.

The code is like this

```
import os
import csv
import psutil # require pip install

# the real CSV file is replaced with a call to this function
def generate_rows():
    for k in range(400000):
        yield ','.join(str(i * 10 + k) for i in range(35))


def memory_test():
    proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print('BEGIN', proc.memory_info().rss)

    fieldnames = ['field_' + str(i) for i in range(35)]
    reader = csv.DictReader(generate_rows(), fieldnames)
    result = []
    for row in reader:
        result.append(row)

    print('  END', proc.memory_info().rss)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    memory_test()
```

In the code above the program will `print` the memory usage (which requires `psutil` installed) and the result is like

```
BEGIN 12623872
  END 2006462464
```

You can see by the end of the process it would take nearly 2GB memory.

But if I copy each row, the memory usage become lower.

```
def memory_test():
    proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print('BEGIN', proc.memory_info().rss)

    fieldnames = ['field_' + str(i) for i in range(35)]
    reader = csv.DictReader(generate_rows(), fieldnames)
    result = []
    for row in reader:
        # MAKE A COPY
        row_copy = {key: value for key, value in row.items()}
        result.append(row_copy)

    print('  END', proc.memory_info().rss)
    return result
```

The result is like

```
BEGIN 12726272
  END 1289912320
```

It only takes about 1.29G memory, much less.

(I tested the code on 64-bit Ubuntu and got those results.)

Why does this happen? Is it proper to copy the rows from a `DictReader`?

Comment: Btw, if you want to make this code more efficient you'd write `result = list(csv.DictReader(generate_rows(), fieldnames))` -- this avoids appending to a list several times, which causes CPython to keep reallocating memory to increase the size of the list.

Comment: @elias Indeed. I just kept the code the way it looks like because there're some changes to make to the `row` object in the real code.

Comment: It might still be worth to move those changes into a function and turn it into a list comprehension `result = [change_row(row) for row in csv.DictReader(...)]`, if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `print(row)`, you will find that `row` is an `OrderedDict`. In your second example, you replace this `OrderedDict` with a normal `dict`. They are different.

You can get the same results by using `OrderedDict` in second example:

```
for row in reader:
    from collections import OrderedDict
    # MAKE A COPY
    row_copy = OrderedDict({key: value for key, value in row.items()})
    result.append(row_copy)
```